# Is there a way to decrypt/deobfuscate pyarmor scripts?

Tags: python, pyarmor

I am trying to decompile a python exe and I got the .py but it is obfuscated with pyarmor. I was wondering if there was a way to decrypt/deobfuscate this?

````
pyarmor_runtime()
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'PYARMOR\x00\x00\x03\x07\x00B\r\r\n\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x0 ...etc```
````

Comment: check this https://github.com/u0pattern/PyArmor-Deobfuscator